# Prolog Beginner: How to unify with arithmetic comparison operators or how to get a set var to range of values

Tags: prolog, clpfd

I am new to Prolog.  I need to write an integer adder that will add numbers between 0-9 to other numbers 0-9 and produce a solution 0-18.  This is what I want to do:

```
% pseudo code
add(in1, in2, out) :-
    in1 < 10,
    in2 < 10,
    out < 18.
```

I would like to be able to call it like this:

To check if it is a valid addition:

```
?- add(1,2,3).
true.
?- add(1,2,4).
false.
```

With one missing variable:

```
?- add(X,2,3).
X = 1.
?- add(1,4,X).
X = 5.
```

With multiple missing variables:

```
?- add(X,Y,Z).
% Some output that would make sense.  Some examples could be:
X=1, Y=1, Z=2 ;
X=2, Y=1, Z=3 ......
```

I realize that this is probably a pretty simplistic question and it is probably very straightforward.  However, according to the [Prolog tutorial](http://boklm.eu/prolog/page_14.html) I am using:

> "Unlike unification Arithmetic Comparison Operators operators cannot be used to give values to a variable. The can only be evaluated when every term on each side have been instantiated."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

```
lessThanTen(9).
lessThanTen(8).
lessThanTen(7).
lessThanTen(6).
lessThanTen(5).
lessThanTen(4).
lessThanTen(3).
lessThanTen(2).
lessThanTen(1).
lessThanTen(0).

addSimple(Add1,Add2,Sol) :-
    lessThanTen(Add1),
    lessThanTen(Add2),
    Sol is Add1+Add2.
```

Answer (score 6):

All modern Prolog systems provide finite domain constraints, which are true relations that can (in contrast to more low-level arithmetic predicates like is/2 and >/2) be used in all directions. In SWI-Prolog:

```
:- use_module(library(clpfd)).

plus(X, Y, Z) :-
        [X,Y] ins 0..9,
        X + Y #= Z.
```

Results for your examples:

```
?- plus(1,2,3).
true.

?- plus(1,2,4).
false.

?- plus(X,2,3).
X = 1.

?- plus(1,4,X).
X = 5.

?- plus(X,Y,Z).
X in 0..9,
X+Y#=Z,
Y in 0..9,
Z in 0..18.
```

Since the predicate can be used in all directions, it does no longer make sense to call it "add/3", as that would imply a direction, but the predicate truly describes when the relation holds and is thus more general.

Answer (score 1):

What about this?:

```
add(X,Y,Z) :-
        Z is X + Y,
        X < 10,
        Y < 10,
        Z < 19.
```

Problem: this works nicely for queries of the form `add(1,1,X)` because `Z`'s instantiated before the `<` calls, but fails when you ask `add(X,1,2)`. You could use `var/1` to distinguish the kind of query (`var/1` tells you whether a variable's uninstantiated or not), but that sounds like a lot of pain.

Comment: Yeah that doesn't work because what you described in your answer.